# I need a SQL Query as follows

Tags: sql

This is my following question please have a look in the code snippet.

Hi, I have two tables Table A, Table B as follows:

```
**Table A**                 **Table B**
Reg Id (ex: 217)              Session Name (ex: Section A, Section B)
                              First Choice
                              Second Choice
                              Third Choice
                              Reg Id
```

I need the result as follows:

```
**Reg id**  **Section A**      **Section B**     **Section C**
217          First Choice       First Choice      First Choice
             Second Choice      Second Choice     Second Choice
             Third Choice       Third Choice      Third Choice
```

Comment: Removed the DBMS tag spam, when you decide which DBMS you're using, please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: does "Table B" have a reg id?  if not there is no way to get the results you want.

Comment: Yes Table B contains reg id.

Comment: Don't understand why table A has an Id with no data, and table B has a table with an Id with Data.  Why not just use one table instead of two?

Comment: It does have data but in this case it's irrelevant, I need to show all three choices under those sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I wold do it.  Join for each column.

```
SELECT A.RegID,
       BSecA.FirstChoice || ', ' || BSecA.SecondChoice || ', ' || BSecA.ThirdChoice as SectionA,
       BSecB.FirstChoice || ', ' || BSecB.SecondChoice || ', ' || BSecB.ThirdChoice as SectionB,
       BSecC.FirstChoice || ', ' || BSecC.SecondChoice || ', ' || BSecC.ThirdChoice as SectionC 
FROM TableA AS A
LEFT JOIN TableB AS BsecA ON A.RegID = BsecA.RegID AND BsecA.SectionName = "Section A"
LEFT JOIN TableB AS BsecB ON A.RegID = BsecB.RegID AND BsecB.SectionName = "Section B"
LEFT JOIN TableB AS BsecC ON A.RegID = BsecC.RegID AND BsecC.SectionName = "Section C"
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the quick response. I didn't get BSecA, BSecB, BSecC part, B is a table here

Comment: No idea what your comment means.  I edited the code to show the use of aliases because maybe that is what you don't understand.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to execute the query and I got following error don't know why      Error in SELECT clause: expression near '|'.
Unable to parse query text. please help thanks

Comment: @Inferno -- I can't help you unless you tell me what platform you are using

Comment: @Inferno I found a typo -- I was missing commas after SectionA and SectionB

Comment: @Inferno if you are using mysql replace `||` with `+`

Comment: Hi, Unfortunate I got an error but thanks for the help

Comment: @inforno -- I'm not omniscient, you'd have to tell me what the error is for me to help.